# Rename file as the value of a content in a vector

Tags: r

i am trying to do a loop to unzip hundreads of files. However, I want to rename the file after unzipping as the number of the previous unziped file. Here is the code:

```
zip_postos <- setwd("ZIP_Postos")
zip_postos <- list.files(zip_postos)
postos <- setwd("Postos")
for (i in 1:184){
  unzip(zip_postos[[2]], "CHUVAS.MDB", exdir = postos)
  file.rename("CHUVAS.MDB", paste(zip_postos[[2]]))
}
```

I know the paste part is wrong, but I don't know to solve it. How could I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Nonetheless, I want to select the value that is in the vector and rename the file as this name. The name of the file is gonna be a number with ".zip". I want to take this number and rename the file as so. zip_postos is the list of the files that is inside the directory I am working. I want to select the value of the vector and rename the extracted file in the other directory that I am unzipping the files.

Comment: could you post a reproducible example

Comment: list.files("C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Mestrado_PEC/Data Mining/Exercício Computacional/Modelagem/Grande/ZIP_Postos")
  [1] "02043018.ZIP" "02044000.ZIP" "02044004.ZIP" "02044027.ZIP" "02044037.ZIP" "02044038.ZIP". 

Then, I want to take, every file unzip to a directory. But when I extract them, the file inside it is called "CHUVAS.MDB". So I want to rename it to the same name of the zip file but using a loop, as they are hundreds.

Something like:

 "02043018.ZIP" --> "02043018.MDB"

I tried to use the code posted, but I don't know how to select the value of the list.files vector.

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood clearly, but just give a try to rename files like this after unzipping `for(i in 1:184){ unzip(zip_postos[i], "CHUVAS.MDB", exdir = postos); file.rename(pattern="CHUVAS.MDB", paste(zip_postos[i], '.MDB', sep = ""))}`

Comment: Tha worked almost pretty much fine! I Just added some gsub function to take out ".ZIP". The final code became like this: 

    for(i in 1:184){ 
      setwd("C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Mestrado_PEC/Data Mining/Exercício Computacional/Modelagem/Grande/ZIP_Postos")
      zip_postos <- list.files()
      unzip(zip_postos[[i]], "CHUVAS.MDB", exdir = postos)
      setwd("C:/Users/Bruno/Documents/Mestrado_PEC/Data Mining/Exercício Computacional/Modelagem/Grande/Teste")
      file.rename("CHUVAS.MDB", paste(gsub("\\.ZIP", "", zip_postos[[i]]), '.MDB', sep = ""))
}